# Booting directly to a Virtualbox VDI?

Tags: grub2, virtualbox

I'm have Ubuntu 14.04 installed, and I have Windows 8.1 as a Virtualbox VDI.

I would like to configure GRUB to allow me to boot directly into the Virtualbox VDI.

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusing the Operating System with a virtual machine.  You could execute a startup script causing the VDI to be loaded, but Ubuntu needs to be running prior to beginning the VM processes.

The form of the command would be `vboxmanage startvm <vm/name/here>` - you can peruse the help files of VirtualBox to learn more.

Comment: I was hoping to boot up Ubuntu at a minimal run level and then execute the Virtualbox hyper-visor with Windows.

Comment: It may be more expedient to run a dual-boot system